# How to filter array of objects where object has property tagId or keywordId in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects and I am trying to filter it by checking if the object has property tagId or keywordId. I thought about this but not sure if it's the correct way.

```
const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.tagId !== undefined || product.keywordId !== undefined)
```

Is there better way to achieve the above-explained result and get a filtered array of objects which include either tagId or keywordid?

Comment: yes it's typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically manually creating comparisons that already exist as `hasOwnProperty()` in object prototype

```
const filteredProducts = 
     products.filter(product => product.hasOwnProperty('tagId') || product.product.hasOwnProperty('keywordId'))

//Or using `Array#some()`
const filteredProducts = 
     products.filter(product => ['tagId','keywordId']
                                  .some(prop => product.hasOwnProperty(prop)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` on product object.
Something like this -

```js
const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.hasOwnProperty("tagId") || product.hasOwnProperty('keywordId"))
```